# How to set the color of inkeditor in pdf.js 3.0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

With pdf.js 3.0 ink- and freetext-editor were introduced. How to set color, size and so on in javascript?

I tried to set the value of the html-input-Element, but without success.